# How to clip all shapefiles, layers, etc associated with global map of Mars

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, geology, exogeography, mars

I'm working on a project where I've found an open source NASA .mxd of shapefiles, layers, metadata, geology, a 30x30 graticule that splits the lat and long into 30 degree square polygons, etc.  I only want to use data that exists between the equator and 30 degrees latitude in both northern and southern hemisphere.  How would you clip this data without having to select a region to clip by hand for all the different raster and vector layers (there are a lot of them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the **[Clip (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000)** for vector layers and the **[Clip (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009n000000)** for raster layers both in **[batch mode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000)**. In the first case, you need a clip feature, so you have to draw a rectangle of your area of interest. Instead, in the second case, you can directly specify the four coordinates defining the minimum bounding rectangle to be clipped. Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also consider using a loop in Python and iterating through every feature you want to select features in another layer with. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/81286-Batch-clip-using-arcpy-script. I find setting batch mode parameters to be a tedious task :)

Comment: I'm agree with you @AlexTereshenkov. I'd use a simple batch script with GDAL/OGR instead, but this is the answer to another question. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The [Clip Workspace Model](http://www.esri.ca/en/content/there-geoprocessing-tool-or-model-which-will-clip-entire-workspace-geodatabase-or-feature) looks like it could work for your NASA .mxd.  I personally only came across it recently and have not had a chance to test it.  The download includes the toolbox, documentation, and a sample .mxd with data to test with.

It is a rather simple model which iterates through your workspace.  Uses the Clip (Analysis) tool and therefore will not work for raster datasets.

The description of the model is as follows:

> This model clips all of the features within a workspace or feature dataset. Application would include clipping an entire geodatabase to create a subset of the data for a specific project.

[Download Page](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=2CA982BC-1422-2418-7F11-D7B846758CD0) on the ArcGIS Resource Center

Comment: Realized that the data you were provided with is not in a geodatabase.  Unless you import your data into one for clipping purposes...the answer by @afalciano is likely your best bet.  Still a useful model for future use.